# Using Drupal Commerce Product Reference Field, missing products

Tags: commerce

I've followed instructions here: https://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-1/issue-1/building-drupal-commerce-product-display

When I create my Product Display, the list of products to choose from is missing most options, as can be seen here: [image: limited options to choose from]

I have many more products under "Dips" added, but they aren't showing up. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting of this field. It looks like it is set to 10. Just make it blank and it should allow for all of the products to be shown.

[image: Product reference field edit form]

Comment: It is set to blank, not ten

Comment: Have you tried clearing all of your caches?

Comment: Yes I have cleared the cache

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that this module appears to have a hidden default of showing only 10 products, even though it says "Leave blank to show unlimited." In my product display content type, for the product reference field, I set the Options list limit to 100, even though I only have 16 products. Voila!! All my products are showing now to select for product reference.